# Apply CSS style to first table cell on row hover

Tags: css, hover

I have a table row with two cells. How can I make it so that when I hover the row, only the background of the first table cell changes color?

```
#formTable tr:hover {
   background:red; // only want the first cell to change...
                   // ...this will do the whole row
}
```

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This should work:

```
#formTable tr:hover td:first-child {
   background:red;
}
```

:first-child: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:first-child

Answer (score 3):

this will only the change the first cell of the first row:

```
#formTable tr:first-child:hover td:first-child{
    background-color: red;
}
```

this will change the first cell of any row:

```
#formTable tr:hover td:first-child{
    background-color: red;
}
```